# how to execute Future payments on server-side

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've completed 1st two steps mention on this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/) and working on 3rd step **"Call the Payment API, using your back-end server."**

For step 3, I have **access_token**, **corelation id** and **amount**

I've found following code for step3 in curl. So, I've converted following **curl command to PHP code**, for which I've two questions:

1) Is it converted correctly?

2) If yes, then what can be the issue for getting blank page in response from PayPal ?

Curl code:

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/capture' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Paypal-Application-Correlation-Id: c2edbd6e97b14ff2b19ddb8eec9d264c" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer WfXdnxmyJtdF4q59ofxuQuAAk6eEV-Njm6puht3Nk3w" \
-d '{
       "amount":{
          "currency":"USD",
          "total":"1.50"
       },
       "is_final_capture":true
    }'
```

This is what I've tried with my understanding, on the basis of above code :

```
static public function executePayment2( $refresh_token, $correlation_id, $fee_amount )
{
    $data = array(
        "amount" => array(
            "currency" => "USD",
            "total" => $fee_amount
        ),
        "is_final_capture" => "true"
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init( "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/capture" );        

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $refresh_token,      //Need to set $refresh_token
                'Paypal-Application-Correlation-Id: ' . $correlation_id      //Need to set $correlation_id
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        )
    );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );   //Make it all happen and store response   
}
```

Comment: No response till yet ?

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate your mobile app with PayPal Mobile SDK 2.0, your customers can give permission to be billed multiple times in the future without logging into their PayPal account. PayPal payments (not credit cards) are supported. The basic...

Comment: I've mentioned above that these steps are completed. I'm on last step.